# How to attach jQuery event exactly on some DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to attach event exactly on some element in DOM structure. Let's say, I have this structure:

```
<form>
  <input id="in1">
  <div>
    <input id="in2">
    <input id="in3">
  </div>
</form>
```

Then I attach events to form elements using selectors which come from some user data, and one of them is like this:

```
$(form).on('focusout', 'div', function() { ... });
```

As a result, this handler is attached to all inputs within 'div' element.

How can I avoid such attachment?

Is there any possibility to check whether exact element has ability to handle some event or not?

Comment: Erm... the event is attached to the form, and then the handler is only called if there is a `div` somewhere between `event.srcElement||event.target` and `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind events to individual element using id.

```
$('#in2').on('focusout',  function() { ... });
```

You can bind events to multiple elements by having comma separate ids.

```
$('#in2,#in3').on('focusout',  function() { ... });
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't enter id's, they are entered by user. I know only id of form. Moreover, form has dynamic elements and it's not possible to attach handlers directly.